# vba, add formula to a cell via code, name error appears

Tags: excel, addition, formula, vba

I am trying to add a formula to a cell via code:

```
Cells(5, 10).Formula = "=SUMIF(Data!$C:$C,Ëèñò1!$A5,Data!H:H)/$B$1"
Cells(6, 10).Formula = "=SUM(F6:F7)"
```

After this code assigns formulas those cells I get #name error value and to see actual values I have to select those cells, press F2 and then press Enter. After true values appear in the cells instead of error values. How can I avoid these additional actions?

Comment: You sure you have a sheet named `Ëèñò1`?

Comment: That code works fine for me if I have sheets with those two names.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your excel is getting confused on the sheet name `Ëèñò1`. Just Rename your sheet to `Eeno1` and it will start working. I have tried it and its working fine without any issue or any additional action.

Comment: after that your code will be like `Cells(5, 10).Formula = "=SUMIF(Data!$C:$C,Eeno1!$A5,Data!H:H)/$B$1"` `Cells(6, 10).Formula = "=SUM(F6:F7)"`

Comment: Still i can't fix it. I renamed sheet using only english letters. "=СУММЕСЛИ(Data!$C:$C,Interface!$A" & i & ",Data!H:H)/$B$14"

Comment: But I still get # name error, after some manupulations with F2 and Enter it works fine. Actually i have russian version of excel and function like sumif written in russian, in addition, recently installed 64 bit excel, i do not know if there is any relation to my problem.